# How to make a 8 bit binary value

Tags: linux, binary

I just implement obase=2 method to convert the decimal to 8 bit binary. but I AM not getting zeros when I convert decimals such as 1 and 2 it just output decimal 1 as binary 1 (without zeros) but I want to get all the decimals with 8 bits with the leading zeros. What can I do for that?

here is the code I used

```
c=$(echo "obase=2,$d" | bc)
echo binary $c
```

Assume $d stores all the decimal values from 0-255 [image: here is the output I getting]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text.  Just paste the text.  Also, clean your monitor.

Comment: You might find the following question and answer to be useful, although from that link, there appears to be no bc only way of doing what you want.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633522/prevent-bc-from-auto-truncating-leading-zeros-when-converting-from-hex-to-binary

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to print formatted data, don't use `echo`.  Use `printf`:

```
$ binaryvalue='101'
$ printf "%08d\n" "$binaryvalue"
00000101
```

The format marker of `%08d` means to print a digit value, eight characters wide, with leading zeroes.